# Looping VBA code for dynamic pivot table update

Tags: excel, vba

I have found a solution to dynamically adjust pivot table filters from an excel cell which is working great; See here:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As 
    Range)
    'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only 
    updates when cell
    'D1 or D2 is touched
    If Intersect(Target, Worksheets("test").Range("D1:D2")) Is Nothing 
    Then Exit Sub

    'Set the Variables to be used
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim Field As PivotField
    Dim NewCat As String

    'Here you amend to suit your data
    Set pt = Worksheets("test").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Name")
    NewCat = Worksheets("test").Range("D1").Value

    'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table
    With pt
    Field.ClearAllFilters
    Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
    pt.RefreshTable
    End With

    End Sub
```

I am trying to figure out how to loop this for example a defined number of times (ie 60) to control a large number of pivot tables all referring to different cells.

the plan is to have a list of employees and each pivot table will show data relevant to that employee, but the employee list will be dynamic.

EDIT:
Please see image of what i am trying to achieve;
[image: https://imgur.com/a/JzRz9xK]

The end goal is to set up page breaks and quickly refresh and print off individual skill levels for staff appraisals.

Comment: Are the pivot tables on different sheets?

Comment: if you create a [mcve] of how you tried to accomplish your goal and what is not working we can help you easier. right now, you are asking us to write the looping code for you and providing only vague specifications where we cannot possibly know the details of your workbook

Comment: Have you thought about solving your task with slicers? see [https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2011/03/07/filter-multiple-pivot-tables-with-excel-2010-slicers/]

Comment: Have you considered using 2 arrays, one of Cells (`Array("D1:D2", "F1:F2", "G1,G7")`, et cetera), and the other of corresponding PivotTables (`Array("PivotTable2", "PivotTable3", "Copy of PivotTable1")`, et cetera)?

Comment: This is what i am struggling with logically, the code i have works for one PivotTable, but i dont know how to even start implementing a loop as the usual 
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 1 To 3
            Cells(i, 1).Value = 100
        Next i                                                    doesn't seem appropriate

Comment: Also, look up Dynamic Named Ranges - such that you could use `If Intersect(Target, Worksheets("test").Range("Employee_List")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`, and set the Named Range to `=Sheet1!$D$1:INDEX(test!$B:$B,MAX(1,COUNTA(test!$B:$B)),1)`

Comment: Finally:  Is there a specific reason why you *need* 60 PivotTables?  That seems **horrifically** inefficient - could you do it better using 1 PivotTable with a Page Filter?

Comment: Please see main post edit. any alternatives are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your image, this seems to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

You want a list of Users and their Skills.  You have decided that this requires Multiple PivotTables.  I propose instead a multi-column PivotTable, with a Blank Line between Users:
[image: Image of Data Table, Pivot Table, and Pivot Fields]

In addition to turning off Subtotals for "Name", you also need to "Insert blank line after each item label" and **not** "Display subtotals at the top of the group":
[image: Image showing the Pivot Field Options]

(Incidentally - when working from Multiple PivotTables, especially ones that use the same PivotCache, [the `PivotTable.ManualUpdate` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.manualupdate) is very useful to reduce redundant recalculation!)

Comment: That would work ideally, however I was hoping to break each employee down into its own page so all 60 can be printed in 1 go onto separate sheets

Comment: Update: I just noticed the 'Insert Page break after each item' checkbox.. Definitely a lot simpler than i was making it!

Comment: @DeanCohen You might also find Custom Number Formats (e.g.`[=4]"Trained";[=2]"Training in Progress";[=0]"Untrained"`) useful to display the text values instead of numbers - have a play, then (if needed) post a new question about that?

Comment: Thank you for that little bonus tip! never knew that was possible either.. super useful and thank you for your help :)